# Redimensionar imagens usando Bootstrap 5.1?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, react

e no CSS #header .imagem {
width: 100% }

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Em vez de especificares a % talvez experimenta meter uma width e uma height especifica em px. A questão foi um pouco redundante, nem deu para entender muito bem!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).